# Activity's onDestroy method is not being called after swiping from background

Tags: android

i have implemented activity's lifecycle callback methods, when i swipe the activity from the background. `onDestroy` method is not being called, i searched for the answers and i got one from one stating that

"Swiping the app from the task list basically means "kill this app right now" it's not given any time to perform an `onDestroy`. None of the lifecycle methods will be called"

But in my case, sometimes `onDestroy` method is being called and sometimes not, i am unable to understand this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that your onDestroy method will be called at all. You can call onDestroy by calling `finish()` on your activity. The system calls onDestroy only for saving space. You can take a look here: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy%28%29). What is important for you to know is that you have to be totally sure that this method will be called before you put some code in it.